# Set Custom Font To UILabel in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, custom-font

Here, I want to set custom font(getting "Font Name" from backend) to UILabel, without adding font files in xCode project.

Please help if find any solution.

Currently I am trying with "Inkwell" in iOS. Here is the link -> https://github.com/ninjaprox/Inkwell

steps which I have followed:

1. Installed pod 'Inkwell', '~> 1.2'
2. Added Google API Key in AppDelegate like, Inkwell.shared.APIKey =
   "Api key here"
3. import "Inkwell"
4. In viewWillAppear, updating label font:

   ```
   let font = Font(family: "Droid Sans", variant: .regular)

   fontOperation = Inkwell.shared.font(for: font, size: fontSize) { uifont in
       print("Font name -> \(String(describing: uifont))")

       self.lblTestFont.font = uifont ?? self.defaultFont
       self.lblTestFont.text = "text"
   }
   ```

But getting "Font name" nil. Font Operation failed.

How I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

To use custom font in iOS app you need to add those font in info.plist file and also add those font in project.

Once you do all these step then you can use the following code to check that our custom font is available to use or not.

```
//it will list all the fonts available 
for fontFamily in UIFont.familyNames {

   print(UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: fontFamily))
}
```

Comment: I want to use fonts without adding font files in project!

Comment: as far as I know, I think its not possible. You need to add the resources (like fonts) in Xcode project to use them.

Comment: Actually here I found "Inkwell" ->  https://github.com/ninjaprox/Inkwell. I am using Custom Fonts Library, which basically Loads and uses the provided Font. 
please check shared link above

Comment: The point which I want to state is, i am not able to catch parsed Font here in iOS demo. I need help in resolve that issue.